# Exporting Results of Script to CSV

Tags: powershell

I've been searching for a script that simply lists folders in a share and their size. I found the following but I'm getting hung up on how to export the output I'm seeing to an easy to read CSV. It amazes me how something so simple has turned into something difficult. Suggestions welcome!

```
$colItems = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\user.name\Desktop" | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | Sort-Object
foreach ($i in $colItems)
{
    $subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
    $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

}
```

Comment: can you post an example of what you would like the resulting csv to be formated as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your script:

```
## C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Test\SO_50359947.ps1
$colItems = Get-ChildItem "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop" |
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object

$data = ForEach ($i in $colItems){
    $subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse -force -ea 0|
        Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} |
            Measure-Object -Property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Folder = $i.FullName
        Size = "{0,10:N2} MB" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB)
    }
}
$data

#$data | Export-Csv "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop\your.csv" -NoType
```

Sample output (on a different tree)

```
> $data

Folder          Size
------          ----
Q:\test\2018\03       0,37 MB
Q:\test\2018\04       0,83 MB
Q:\test\2018\05     383,57 MB
```

Uncomment the last line to write to a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using custom objects:

```
Get-ChildItem "$home\Desktop" -Directory |
    ForEach-Object {
        $contents = Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            FolderName = $_.Name
            SizeMB = [Math]::Round(($contents | Where-Object PsIsContainer -eq $false | Measure-Object -property Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB,2)
            SubFolders = ($contents | Where-Object PsIsContainer -eq $true | Measure-Object).Count
            Files = ($contents | Where-Object PsIsContainer -eq $false | Measure-Object).Count
        }
    }
```

This gives output like this:

```
FolderName   SizeMB SubFolders Files
----------   ------ ---------- -----
Folder1      438.38         19   124
Folder2    34925.72        306  3779
```

To send this to CSV, simply append the following after the last bracket:

```
| Export-Csv "$home\Desktop\Folders.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways to do this, but I think the least confusing would be to simply add that information to the item using `Add-Member`. Then output the desired data via `Export-Csv`.

```
$colItems = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\user.name\Desktop" | 
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | 
    Sort-Object | 
    %{ Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'FolderSize' -NotePropertyValue (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum) -PassThru}

$colItems | Select FullName,FolderSize | Export-Csv -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

Please assign to some variable after getting all the file details from the desktop/any location and create the excel

```
$subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem "$home\Desktop" -Directory |
    ForEach-Object {
        $contents = Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            FolderName = $_.Name
            SizeMB = [Math]::Round(($contents | Where-Object PsIsContainer -eq $false | Measure-Object -property Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB,2)
            SubFolders = ($contents | Where-Object PsIsContainer -eq $true | Measure-Object).Count
            Files = ($contents | Where-Object PsIsContainer -eq $false | Measure-Object).Count
        }
    }

$subFolderItems | out-file C:\Users\thiyagu.a.selvaraj\Desktop\PowerShell\FileSizeOutput.xls
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, using CSV for your use case isn't the best plan because (in my folder) there are files that are over 1000 MB, so csv will break up some file sizes.  To make a tab delimited file, which can just as easily be parsed by most systems, simply modify your scripts output string.

I changed the -- to a tab character, and added an output at the end of the line

`` "{0}`t{1:N2} MB" -f $i.fullname,($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) >> output.csv ``

The final script is below; you will probably need to change `output.csv` to your prefered output file location.

```
$colItems = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\user.name\Desktop" | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | Sort-Object
foreach ($i in $colItems)
{
    $subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
    "{0}`t{1:N2} MB" -f $i.fullname,($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) >> output.csv
}
```

Comment: I disagree, a simple tab won't solve the problem. Powershell also double quotes all entries so no problem with the comma. And please get rid of that very ugly string concatenation when already using the string format operator: `"{0}\`t{1:N2} MB" -f $i.fullname,($subFolderItems.sum/1MB) >>output.csv`